# Need explanation of ARM Cortex-M3 assembly instruction in CMSIS to __set_PRIMASK

Tags: assembly, gcc, cortex-m

Below is a code snippet from the ARM CMSIS library that is used to set the value of the **PRIMASK** register.

```
/**
 * @brief  Set the Priority Mask value
 *
 * @param  priMask  PriMask
 *
 * Set the priority mask bit in the priority mask register
 */
static __INLINE void __set_PRIMASK(uint32_t priMask)
{
   register uint32_t __regPriMask         __ASM("primask");
   __regPriMask = (priMask);
}
```

The part that I don't understand is the inline assembly instruction

```
__ASM("primask");
```

I haven't read anything about addressing registers by name in this way.  How can you have inline assembly without an op-code first?  Is this assigning **__regPriMask** to this register location?  Can anyone point to a reference document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
register uint32_t __regPriMask __ASM("primask");
```

...is the declaration of a [local register variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html#Local-Reg-Vars) called `__regPriMask` that is stored in the `primask` register.

In other words, assigning to that register variable will set the value of the register `primask`.